# Entity Framework doesn't create tables in Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I've just started to learn ASP.Net MVC and Entity Framework using some tutorial and I have a problem.

I created class for Database Connection
**OdeToFoodDb.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace OdeToFood.Models
{
    public class OdeToFoodDb : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Restaurant> Restaurants { get; set; }
        public DbSet<RestaurantReview> Reviews { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and two classes **Restaurant.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace OdeToFood.Models
{
    public class Restaurant
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public ICollection<RestaurantReview> Review { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and **RestaurantReview.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace OdeToFood.Models
{
    public class RestaurantReview
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Rating { get; set; }
        public string Body { get; set; }
        public int RestaurantId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then I try Add Connection
[image]

[image]

And I've got database but it doesn't contain tables RestaurantReviews or Restaurants

[image]

but my tutorial says that I get these tables automatically. What I did wrong? How to make it create tables I need?

Comment: Can you post link to your tutorial?

Comment: No, I can't, it's video tutorial  Building Applications with ASP.NET MVC 4 from pluralsight.com.

Comment: Did you run your demo app?

Answer (score 1):

In your Package Manager Console, run the following command

```
Update-Database -ProjectName <YourProject.DataLayer>
```

Check if your connection string is pointing to your expected database